# If $f(x) \leq a \leq g(x)$, $f(x) \leq b \leq g(x)$, and for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x$ such that $g(x) - f(x) < \epsilon$, then $a = b$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f, g$ are real-valued functions and $a, b$ are real numbers. If $f(x) \leq a \leq g(x)$ and $f(x) \leq b \leq g(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x$ such that $g(x) - f(x) < \epsilon$, then $a = b$.

Is this result true? Something similar to it but involving lower and upper sums came up in a proof for the sum rule in integration ($\int_{a}^{b} (f + g) = \int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{a}^{b} g$) in *Spivak's Calculus*.

Comment: Is $f(x)\leq a\leq g(x)$ and $f(x)\leq b\leq g(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: @Dave Yes, and thank you Sambo for the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is true. Let $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$
g(x) - f(x) < \epsilon
$$

Remark that from your conditions, $g(x) \geq a$ and $-f(x) \geq -b$, so we have:

$$
\epsilon > g(x) - f(x) \geq a-b
$$

Similarly, we have $g(x) \geq b$ and $-f(x) \geq -a$, so:

$$
\epsilon > g(x) - f(x) \geq b-a = -(a-b)
$$

And so we have:

$$
|a-b| < \epsilon
$$

Since this holds for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can conclude that $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

Note: $|b-a| \le g(x) - f(x)$ for all $x$.  So for all $\epsilon$ there is an $x$ so that $\epsilon > g(x) - f(x) \ge |b-a|$.   So $0 \le |b-a| < \epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$.  There is only one non-negative real number that is smaller than all positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality assume that $a\leq b$. Then you have
$$
f(x)\leq a \leq b \leq g(x) \quad \text{for every}  \ x,
$$
and therefore

$$
0\leq b-a\leq g(x)-f(x) \quad \text{for every} \ x,
$$
If for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $x$ such that $g(x)-f(x)< \varepsilon$, we conclude that
$$
0\leq b-a \leq \varepsilon \quad \text{for every} \ \varepsilon >0,
$$
and then $b=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Given your scenario, we can find a sequence $x_n$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(x_n)-g(x_n)| =0$.

Therefore, $a=b$ holds.